# How to access keys of maps using a string pointer

Tags: c++, maps

I am trying to access a map by using a string* pointer instead of its actual value.  Whenever I use this pointer the maps key is returning the wrong value.

```
mymap_comp_for_c.insert(pair<string, unsigned short int>("M", 0b1110000));
```

`_c_parts[1]` holds the value of M

but 
`value+= mymap_comp_for_c[c_parts[1]]` is returning the incorrect integer that is assigned to "M"

Comment: Make an [MCVE] and show that here.

Comment: You need to know the difference between a pointer and an object. Your map's key is STD::string and that's what you have to pass. Dereference the pointer to get the underlying string object.

Comment: @jlj6990 If you feel that none of the answers given answered your question, consider rephrasing the question.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer like "M" will not match later another pointer "M" or a &string("M"). 
It's the same type (const char*) but a different value, and you use as a key the *value* of the pointer which is different.

```
map<string*,int> x;
x["m"] = 5;
int y = x["m"]; // y not necessarily 5.
```

"m" in line 3 and "m" in the previous line have different pointer values. The compiler might optimize with string pooling, leading you to believe that it worked, but it is actually a hard to find bug.

Answer (score 0):

If `c_parts` really is an array of `std::string*` you need to dereference the pointers in it with `*c_parts[index]` before you can use it to extract data from your map. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, int> mymap_comp_for_c;

    mymap_comp_for_c.emplace("M", 0b1110000); // emplace: easier than creating the pair manually

    // an array of std::string*    
    std::string M = "M";
    std::array<std::string*, 2> c_parts = {nullptr, &M};

    for(auto& strptr : c_parts) {
        if(strptr) { // check that it's not a nullptr
            // dereference the std::string* and print the value in the map
            std::cout << std::hex << mymap_comp_for_c[*strptr] << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This prints `70` (hex) as it should.